# 2D Array in Kotlin

Tags: arrays, kotlin

How do you make a 2D Int array in Kotlin? I'm trying to convert this code to Kotlin:

```java
int[][] states = new int[][] {
      new int[]{-android.R.attr.state_pressed}, // not pressed
      new int[] { android.R.attr.state_pressed}  // pressed
};
int[] colors = new int[] {
      foregroundColor,
      accentColor,
      accentColor
};
ColorStateList myList = new ColorStateList(states, colors);
```

Here is one attempt I tried, where the first 2D array didn't work, but I got the 1D array to work:

```kotlin
//This doesn't work:
var states: IntArray = intArrayOf(
    intArrayOf(-android.R.attr.state_pressed), // not pressed
    intArrayOf(android.R.attr.state_pressed)  // pressed
);
//This array works:
var colors: IntArray = intArrayOf(
    foregroundColor,
    accentColor,
    accentColor
);
val myList: ColorStateList = ColorStateList(states, colors);
```

Answer (score 80, accepted):

You are trying to put your IntArrays inside another array to make it 2-dimensional.
The type of that array cannot be intArray, which is why this fails.
Wrap your initial arrays with `arrayOf` instead of `intArrayOf`.

```
val even: IntArray = intArrayOf(2, 4, 6)
val odd: IntArray = intArrayOf(1, 3, 5)

val lala: Array<IntArray> = arrayOf(even, odd)
```

Comment: I'm basically creating n 1d arrays and appending those into another array to make a 2d array?

Answer (score 121):

You may use this line of code for an Integer array.

```
val array = Array(row) { IntArray(column) }
```

This line of code is pretty simple and works like 1D array and also can be accessible like java 2D array.

Comment: This work well and just to add here if you want to create a 2D array with nulls you can use that -> val array = Array(row) { arrayOfNulls<Int>(column) }

Comment: Here `row` and `column` are the number of rows and number of columns in your 2D array.

Answer (score 52):

Short Answer:

```
// A 6x5 array of Int, all set to 0.
var m = Array(6) {Array(5) {0} }
```

Here is another example with more details on what is going on:

```
// a 6x5 Int array initialise all to 0
var m = Array(6, {i -> Array(5, {j -> 0})})
```

*The first parameter is the size, the second lambda method is for initialisation.*

This applies for [Object-Type Array](https://kotlinlang.org/docs/arrays.html) ONLY and according to Kotlin docs, the performance is impacted because the primitives are boxed into objects, to avoid auto boxing use the [primitive type arrays intead](https://kotlinlang.org/docs/arrays.html#primitive-type-arrays).

Comment: What about unlimited size?

Comment: how i insert data this?
i try m[0][0]=

Comment: Thank you! Such a simple problem took waaaay too much time. Perfect. I'll be using this from now on.

Answer (score 29):

I have been using this one-liner when creating matrix

```
var matrix: Array<IntArray> = Array(height) { IntArray(width) }
```

Answer (score 17):

**1. Nested `arrayOf` calls**

You can nest calls of `arrayOf`, e.g., to create an Array of `IntArray`, do the following:

```
val first: Array<IntArray> = arrayOf(
    intArrayOf(2, 4, 6),
    intArrayOf(1, 3, 5)
)
```

Note that the `IntArray` itself only takes arguments of type `Int` as arguments, so you cannot have an `IntArray<IntArray>` which obviously does not make much sense anyway.

**2. Use `Array::constructor(size: Int, init: (Int) -> T)` for repeated logic**

If you want to create your inner arrays with some logical behaviour based on the index, you can make use of the `Array` constructor taking a size and an init block:

```
val second: Array<IntArray> = Array(3) {
    intArrayOf(it * 1, it * 2, it * 3, it * 4)
} 
//[[0, 0, 0, 0], [1, 2, 3, 4], [2, 4, 6, 8]]
```

Answer (score 6):

It seems that you are trying to create a `ColorStateList` in Kotlin. The code for that is a bit messy, i'll try to keep it readable:

```
val resolvedColor = Color.rgb(214, 0, 0)
val states = arrayOf(
    intArrayOf(-android.R.attr.state_pressed),
    intArrayOf(android.R.attr.state_pressed)
)

val csl = ColorStateList(
    states,
    intArrayOf(resolvedColor, Color.WHITE)
)
```

Answer (score 3):

You can use a simple 1D (linear) array for this purpose. For example, this is my class for a rectangle array of Double values:

```
/**
 * Rect array of Double values
 */
class DoubleRectArray(private val rows: Int, private val cols: Int) {
    private val innerArray: DoubleArray

    init {
        if(rows < 1) {
            throw IllegalArgumentException("Rows value is invalid. It must be greater than 0")
        }

        if(cols < 1) {
            throw IllegalArgumentException("Cols value is invalid. It must be greater than 0")
        }

        innerArray = DoubleArray(rows*cols)
    }

    /**
     *
     */
    fun get(row: Int, col: Int): Double {
        checkRowAndCol(row, col)
        return innerArray[row*cols + col]
    }

    /**
     *
     */
    fun set(row: Int, col: Int, value: Double) {
        checkRowAndCol(row, col)
        innerArray[row*cols + col] = value
    }

    /**
     *
     */
    private fun checkRowAndCol(row: Int, col: Int) {
        if(row !in 0 until rows) {
            throw ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException("Row value is invalid. It must be in a 0..${rows-1} interval (inclusive)")
        }

        if(col !in 0 until cols) {
            throw ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException("Col value is invalid. It must be in a 0..${cols-1} interval (inclusive)")
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Sad but true, this seems to be the only reasonable way to handle 2D arrays in Kotlin and I cannot even find this in the standard library. My feeling is to advise anyone against using Kotlin for data science, scientific computing, statistics, machine learning etc.

Answer (score 2):

```
package helloWorld

import java.util.Scanner

fun main(){
    val sc = Scanner(System.`in`)
    print("ENTER THE SIZE OF THE ROW: ")
    var row = sc.nextInt()
    println()
    print("ENTER THE SIZE OF COLUMN: ")
    val column = sc.nextInt()
    println()
    var a = Array(row){IntArray(column)}
    for(i in 0 until row){
        when (i) {
            0 -> {
                println("----------${i+1} st ROW'S DATA----------")
            }
            1 -> {
                println("----------${i+1} nd ROW'S DATA----------")
            }
            2 -> {
                println("----------${i+1} rd ROW'S DATA----------")
            }
            else -> {
                println("----------${i+1} th ROW'S DATA----------")
            }
        }
        for(j in 0 until column)
        {
            print("ENTER ${j+1} COLUMN'S DATA: ")
            var data:Int = sc.nextInt()
            a[i][j]=data;
        }
        println()
    }
    println("COLLECTION OF DATA IS COMPLETED")
    for(i in 0 until row){
        for(j in 0 until column){
            print(a[i][j])
            print(" ")
        }
        println()
    }


}
```

It works like this:

[image]

Answer (score 2):

You can create 2D array in kotlin.

```
            var twoDarray = Array(8) { IntArray(8) }
```

this is a example of int 2D array

Comment: Isn't that a 1D array? Please explain. As it is it looks very strange.

Answer (score 1):

Using an **inline** function and a **Pair**:

```
  inline fun<reified T> Pair<Int,Int>.createArray(initialValue:T) = Array(this.first){ Array(this.second){initialValue}}

  // Create m*n Array of Ints filled with 0
  val twoDimArray = Pair(10,20).createArray(0)

  // Create m*n Array of Doubles filled with 0.0
  val twoDimArray = Pair(10,20).createArray(0.0)

  // Create m*n Array of Strings filled with "Value"
  val twoDimArray = Pair(10,20).createArray("Value")

  ...
```

Answer (score 0):

You can create two one dimensional array and add them in new array.

```
val unChecked = intArrayOf(-android.R.attr.state_checked)
val checked = intArrayOf(android.R.attr.state_checked)
val states = arrayOf(unChecked, checked)

val thumbColors = intArrayOf(Color.WHITE, Color.parseColor("#55FFD4"))
val stateList = ColorStateList(states, thumbColors)
```